# If We Validate User Is Logged In or Not, Do We Still Need To Use FORM Tokens To Avoid CSRF Attacks?

Tags: php

Let's assume when a form is submitted, a request is sent to **FormToDatabase.php**

FormToDatabase.php verifies if the user is logged in or not using

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['user'])){
echo 'Log In First';
die();
}
```

When it comes to CSRF, the attacker won't be able to send the request because the user needs to be logged in.

So, is it necessary to use form/link tokens for extra security or not?

Comment: "the attacker won't be able to send the request because the user needs to be logged in."...no, that's not true at all. Because an attack could also happen _after_ the user has already logged in.

Comment: Can you explain a little bit theoretically?

Comment: There are plenty of csrf explainers online already which can probably explain it a lot better than I could in a short comment. But basically there's nothing stopping malicious request being made at any time, so in that sense there's no difference in terms of being logged in or out. In fact in most scenarios such a request could really only succeed once the user is already logged in

Comment: https://www.netsparker.com/blog/web-security/csrf-cross-site-request-forgery/ has quite an in depth guide, for example

Comment: Got it, thank ya all